# Gem or Rake task, etc. to get a high level overview of existing Rails project in Git?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubygems, rake

I'm diving into a large existing Ruby on Rails 3.2 project using Git for version control and am looking to get a quick overview of the project, especially what sections of the code are being most actively developed.

I think I recall there being a gem or a rake task or something to help with this but can't recall any specifics. I've searched StackOverflow and Google without any luck. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can use code climate.

Comment: Or metric fu, if you want a gem.

Comment: There is a great demo of metric fu on Railscasts - http://railscasts.com/episodes/166-metric-fu?view=asciicast